# Pliny named the plant in his book History of Nature

Tags: classical-latin, latin-to-english-translation, academic-latin

The following is a paragraph(critical point) from [Pliny's History of Nature](https://web.archive.org/web/20161229101439/http://www.masseiana.org/pliny.htm#THE%20BOTANY%20OF%20PLINY:%7E:text=an%20unmixed%20blessing.-,THE%20BOTANY%20OF%20PLINY,-The%20identification%20of) :

The identification of plants mentioned in the Natural History is a difficult matter. ... trained botanist hesitates at times to give with any confidence the modern equivalent of an ancient name in some particular context... when certain that a Latin or Greek name is generally equivalent to an English one, the botanist is not sure that a variety included by Pliny, or Theophrastus, under the former should also be included under the latter...

In the above paragraph, the author says that the identification of plants in Pliny's book is complicated, which I understand, but when it says "... modern equivalent of an ancient name...", how to understand it does it mean we know the plant but there is no English name of it? or is it an unidentified plant?

And when the author says "...under the former should also be included under the latter...", what I understand is that variation by ancient people is different from a current variation of plant.

Answer (score 5):

"When certain that a Latin or Greek name is generally equivalent to an English one" means that we know what sort of plant he's describing, but we're not sure whether the category he used lines up with the category we now use.

For example, it's pretty clear that *pīnus* is equivalent to "pine tree". It's where we get the modern name and *pīnus* trees are described as having needles and cones and other features that line up specifically with pines.

But, nowadays "pine tree" has a specific meaning in botany: the 187 species that comprise the Pinoideae subfamily. Which of those 187 species would Pliny have called a *pīnus*? He might have considered some of those to fall into a different category with a different name, or he might have grouped other needle-and-cone-having evergreens in under the category *pīnus*, such as firs.

Simply put, we don't always know whether the ancients grouped their plants in the same way we do nowadays. The science of botany has changed tremendously between Pliny's era and ours, and the language has changed as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, ignoring what type of category use Theophrastus or Pliny, do we know which tree is mentioned by them?

Comment: @AbhishekYadav Well, you can't really separate the type of tree from the category. We define types of trees by how we categorize them.